Benefits obtained by reading the different Lilas from Shrimad Bhagavatam
There are certain stories in Shrimad Bhagavatam which give certain benefits for reading or chanting them in the way mentioned. For example, if one hears Stuti of Lord Narsimha by Prahaladji mentioned in the Bhagavat, Lord Narsimha says:

One who always remembers your activities and My activities also, and who chants the prayers you have offered, becomes free, in due course of time, from the reactions of material activities.(7.10.14)

I would like to have a compilation of all these types of shlokas so that we can chant or hear them according to what we want.

Below are some of the Lilas from Shrimad Bhagavatam and the benedictions obtained by hearing, reading, or reciting them.

Obtaining pure devotion to Lord Vishnu, residence in Dhruvaloka, attainment of wealth, power, longevity or any desired perfection.
Section: SB 4.8 to 4.13 (Activities of Dhruva Mahārāja)
If one simply reads over and over again about Dhruva Mahārāja by
hearing and reading this chapter, one can attain the highest
perfection of life in any way he desires; most importantly, he gets
the chance to become a great devotee. To become a great devotee means
to finish all miserable conditions of materialistic life.
Anyone who hears this narration of Dhruva Mahārāja acquires exalted
qualities like him. For anyone who desires greatness, prowess or
influence, here is the process by which to acquire them, and for
thoughtful men who want adoration, here is the proper means.
The great sage Maitreya recommended: One should chant of the character
and activities of Dhruva Mahārāja both in the morning and in the
evening, with great attention and care, in a society of brāhmaṇas or
other twice-born persons.
Persons who have completely taken shelter of the lotus feet of the
Lord should recite this narration of Dhruva Mahārāja without taking
remuneration. Specifically, recitation is recommended on the full moon
or dark moon day, on the day after Ekādaśī, on the appearance of the
Śravaṇa star, at the end of a particular tithi, or the occasion of
Vyatīpāta, at the end of the month, or on Sunday. Such recitation
should of course be performed before a favorable audience. When
recitation is performed this way, without professional motive, the
reciter and audience become perfect.
Lord Chaitanya Mahaprabhu heard Prahlad and Dhruva Charitra hundreds of times:
"Whenever Sri Gadadhara would recite the Prahlada-caritra and
Dhruva-caritra from Bhagavatam, the Lord would manifest various
symptoms of love. The Lord would hear the glories of Prahlada and
Dhruva hundreds of times." (Sri Caitanya-bhagavata, Antya.10.13-14).


Attaining Vishnuloka, wealth, progeny, success in scholarly pursuits, recognition, driving away bad luck.
Section: SB 4.15 to 4.23 (Activities of Pṛthu Mahārāja)
Any person who describes the great characteristics of King Pṛthu with
faith and determination—whether he reads or hears of them himself or
helps others to hear of them—is certain to attain the very planet
which Mahārāja Pṛthu attained. In other words, such a person also
returns home to the Vaikuṇṭha planets, back to Godhead.
It does not matter whether one is a man or woman. Anyone who, with
great respect, hears this narration of Mahārāja Pṛthu will become the
father of many children if he is without children and will become the
richest of men if he is without money.
Also, one who hears this narration three times will become very
reputable if he is not recognized in society, and he will become a
great scholar if he is illiterate. In other words, hearing of the
narrations of Pṛthu Mahārāja is so auspicious that it drives away all
bad luck.
By hearing the narration of Pṛthu Mahārāja, one can become great,
increase his duration of life, gain promotion to the heavenly planets
and counteract the contaminations of this age of Kali. In addition,
one can promote the causes of religion, economic development, sense
gratification and liberation. Therefore from all sides it is advisable
for a materialistic person who is interested in such things to read
and hear the narrations of the life and character of Pṛthu Mahārāja.


Invoking Lord Vishnu's mercy which is otherwise very difficult to attain and acquiring whatever one wants from Him.
Section: SB 4.24 (The song of Lord Shiva)
Although rendering devotional service to the Supreme Personality of
Godhead and worshiping Him are very difficult, if one vibrates or
simply reads this stotra [prayer] composed and sung by me, he will
very easily be able to invoke the mercy of the Supreme Personality of
Godhead.
The Supreme Personality of Godhead is the dearmost objective of all
auspicious benedictions. A human being who sings this song sung by me
can please the Supreme Personality of Godhead. Such a devotee, being
fixed in the Lord's devotional service, can acquire whatever he wants
from the Supreme Lord.
A devotee who rises early in the morning and with folded hands chants
these prayers sung by Lord Śiva and gives facility to others to hear
them certainly becomes free from all bondage to fruitive activities.


Overcoming fear, protection from plunderers, evil spirits and any kind of disease.
Section: SB 6.8 (Employing the Narayana Kavach or hearing it)
Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: My dear Mahārāja Parīkṣit, one who employs
this armor or hears about it with faith and veneration when afraid
because of any conditions in the material world is immediately freed
from all dangers and is worshiped by all living entities.
This prayer, Nārāyaṇa-kavaca, constitutes subtle knowledge
transcendentally connected with Nārāyaṇa. One who employs this prayer
is never disturbed or put in danger by the government, by plunderers,
by evil demons or by any type of disease.


Making social ceremonies such as marriage extremely auspicious, pleasing forefathers in Pirtrloka, residents of Indraloka, Siddhaloka, etc.
Section: SB 8.18 - 8.23 (Activities of Lord Vamanadeva)
Whenever the activities of Vāmanadeva are described in the course of a
ritualistic ceremony, whether the ceremony be performed to please the
demigods, to please one’s forefathers in Pitṛloka, or to celebrate a
social event like a marriage, that ceremony should be understood to be
extremely auspicious.
There are three kinds of ceremonies—specifically, ceremonies to please
the Supreme Personality of Godhead or the demigods, those performed
for social celebrations like marriages and birthdays, and those meant
to please the forefathers, like the śrāddha ceremony. In all these
ceremonies, large amounts of money are spent for various activities,
but here it is suggested that if along with this there is recitation
of the wonderful activities of Vāmanadeva, certainly the ceremony will
be carried out successfully and will be free of all discrepancies.


Ending material existence / rebirth.
Section: SB 12.10 (Activities of Mārkaṇḍeya Ṛṣi)
O best of the Bhṛgus, this account concerning Mārkaṇḍeya Ṛṣi conveys
the transcendental potency of the Supreme Lord. Anyone who properly
narrates or hears it will never again undergo material existence,
which is based on the desire to perform fruitive activities.


Remaining unaffected by the contamination of Kali Yuga, preventing bad dreams, getting eternal residence in Vaikuntha.
Section: SB 8.2.4 (Gajendra Moksha)
My dear King Parīkṣit, I have now described the wonderful power of
Kṛṣṇa, as displayed when the Lord delivered the King of the elephants.
O best of the Kuru dynasty, those who hear this narration become fit
to be promoted to the higher planetary systems. Simply because of
hearing this narration, they gain a reputation as devotees, they are
unaffected by the contamination of Kali-yuga, and they never see bad
dreams.
Therefore, after getting up from bed in the morning, those who desire
their own welfare — especially the brāhmaṇas, kṣatriyas, vaiśyas and
in particular the brāhmaṇa Vaiṣṇavas — should chant this narration as
it is, without deviation, to counteract the troubles of bad dreams.
My dear devotee, unto those who rise from bed at the end of night and
offer Me the prayers offered by you, I give an eternal residence in
the spiritual world at the end of their lives.


Increasing lifespan, fulfilling material and spiritual desires, becoming famous, attaining liberation, higher planetary systems, not having to ask others for these.
Section: SB 5.7-14 (Studying the life of Mahārāja Bharata)
Devotees interested in hearing and chanting [śravaṇaṁ kīrtanam]
regularly discuss the pure characteristics of Bharata Mahārāja and
praise his activities. If one submissively hears and chants about the
all-auspicious Mahārāja Bharata, one’s life span and material
opulences certainly increase. One can become very famous and easily
attain promotion to the heavenly planets, or attain liberation by
merging into the existence of the Lord. Whatever one desires can be
attained simply by hearing, chanting and glorifying the activities of
Mahārāja Bharata. In this way, one can fulfill all his material and
spiritual desires. One does not have to ask anyone else for these
things, for simply by studying the life of Mahārāja Bharata, one can
attain all desirable things.


Success in any endeavor, ending material suffering.
Section: SB 8.12.46 (Hearing or describing the churning of the Ocean of Milk)
The endeavor of one who constantly hears or describes this narration
of the churning of the Ocean of Milk will never be fruitless. Indeed,
chanting the glories of the Supreme Personality of Godhead is the only
means to annihilate all sufferings in this material world.


Overcoming the dualities of material happiness and distress.
Section: SB 11.23 (Song of the Avantī Brāhmaṇa)
Anyone who listens to or recites to others this song of the sannyāsī,
which presents scientific knowledge of the Absolute, and who thus
meditates upon it with full attention, will never again be overwhelmed
by the dualities of material happiness and distress.


Conquering lust and attaining sobriety.
Section: SB 10.33 (The Rasa Dance)
Anyone who faithfully hears or describes the Lord’s playful affairs
with the young gopīs of Vṛndāvana will attain the Lord’s pure
devotional service. Thus he will quickly become sober and conquer
lust, the disease of the heart.
The extraordinary power of Lord Kṛṣṇa’s conjugal pastimes is clearly
revealed here. Qualitatively, the Lord’s spiritual, loving pastimes
are the diametric opposite of material, lusty affairs, so much so that
simply by hearing about the Lord’s pastimes a devotee conquers sex
desire. By reading pornographic literature or hearing about material
romance, we certainly do not conquer sex desire but rather increase
our lust. But hearing or reading about the Lord’s conjugal affairs has
exactly the opposite effect because they are of the opposite nature,
being purely spiritual. Therefore it is by the causeless mercy of Lord
Kṛṣṇa that He exhibits His rāsa-līlā within this world. If we become
attached to this narration, we will experience the bliss of spiritual
love and thus reject the perverted reflection of that love, which is
called lust. As nicely put by Lord Kṛṣṇa in the Bhagavad-gītā (2.59),
paraṁ dṛṣṭvā nivartate: “Once having directly experienced the Supreme,
one will not return to material pleasures.”


Fulfilling ambitions and attaining the spiritual world.
Section: SB 8.24 (Description of the Matsya Avatar)
One who narrates this description of the Matsya incarnation and King
Satyavrata will certainly have all his ambitions fulfilled, and he
will undoubtedly return home, back to Godhead..


Overcoming jealousy and attaining liberation.
Section: SB 9.10-12 (Pastimes of Lord Ramachandra)
O King Parīkṣit, anyone who aurally receives the narrations concerning
the characteristics of Lord Rāmacandra’s pastimes will ultimately be
freed from the disease of envy and thus be liberated from the bondage
of fruitive activities.


Driving away infamy, sins, and attaining peace.
Chapter: SB 10.56-57 (The Syamantaka Jewel)
This narration, rich with descriptions of the prowess of Lord Śrī
Viṣṇu, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, removes sinful reactions
and bestows all auspiciousness. Anyone who recites, hears or remembers
it will drive away his own infamy and sins and attain peace.


Fulfilling spiritual desires.
Section: SB 10.11-14 (Lord Krishna's childhood pastimes)
Any person who hears or chants these pastimes Lord Murāri performed
with His cowherd friends — the killing of Aghāsura, the taking of
lunch on the forest grass, the Lord’s manifestation of transcendental
forms, and the wonderful prayers offered by Lord Brahmā — is sure to
achieve all his spiritual desires.


Friendly relations with brothers and all living entities.
Chapter: SB 4.30.9 (Activities of the Pracetas)
The Lord continued: Those who remember you every evening of every day
will become friendly with their brothers and with all other living
entities.


The Phalashruti of hearing/reciting/teaching bhakti yoga taught by Uddhava:

From Book 11, Chapter 29
I have repeatedly spoken this knowledge to you with clear reasoning.
Anyone who properly understands it will become free from all doubts
and attain liberation.
Anyone who fixes his attention on these clear answers to your
questions will attain to the eternal, confidential goal of the Vedas —
the Supreme Absolute Truth.
One who liberally disseminates
this knowledge among My devotees is the bestower of the Absolute
Truth, and to him I give My very own self.
He who loudly recites this supreme knowledge, which is the most lucid
and purifying, becomes purified day by day, for he reveals Me to
others with the lamp of transcendental knowledge.
Anyone who regularly listens to this knowledge with faith and
attention, all the while engaging in My pure devotional service, will
never become bound by the reactions of material work.

From Book 11, Chapter 5, verse 52

Anyone who meditates on this pious historical narration with fixed
attention will purify himself,  of all contamination in this very life
and thus achieve the highest spiritual perfection.

Benefits of chanting the story of Maharaja Ambarisha and Durvasa

From Book 9, Chapter 5
Anyone who chants this narration or even thinks of this narration
about the activities of Mahārāja Ambarīṣa certainly becomes a pure
devotee of the Lord.(27)
By the grace of the Lord, those who hear about the activities of
Mahārāja Ambarīṣa, the great devotee, certainly become liberated or
become devotees without delay.(28)

Phalashruti of story of killing Hiranyaksha:

O brāhmaṇas, anyone who hears, chants, or takes pleasure in the
wonderful narration of the killing of the Hiraṇyākṣa demon by the
Lord, who appeared as the first boar in order to deliver the world, is
at once relieved of the results of sinful activities, even the killing
of a brāhmaṇa.
This most sacred narrative confers extraordinary merit, wealth, fame,
longevity and all the objects of one’s desire. On the field of battle
it promotes the strength of one’s vital organs and organs of action.
One who listens to it at the last moment of his life is transferred to
the supreme abode of the Lord, O dear Śaunaka.
From Srimad Bhagavatam 3.19.37-38

Benefits of listening to the narration of puranic literature:

From Bhagavata Purana 12.7.25
I have thoroughly described to you, O brāhmaṇa, the expansion of the
branches of the Vedas by the great sage Vyāsadeva, his disciples and
the disciples of his disciples. One who listens to this narration
will increase in spiritual strength.

Benefits of hearing to the life history of  Lord Krishna:

From Bhagavata Purana 10.90.50
By regularly hearing, chanting and meditating on the beautiful topics
of Lord Mukunda with ever-increasing sincerity, a mortal being will
attain the divine kingdom of the Lord, where the inviolable power of
death holds no sway. For this purpose, many persons, including great
kings, abandoned their mundane homes and took to the forest.

Benefits of listening to story of Citraketu

From Bhagavata Purana 6.17.40-41
Citraketu was a great devotee. If one hears this history of Citraketu
from a pure devotee, the listener also is freed from the conditional
life of material existence.
One who rises from bed early in the morning and recites this history
of Citraketu, controlling his words and mind and remembering the
Supreme Personality of Godhead, will return home, back to Godhead,
without difficulty.

